# UWP XAML - How can I draw shapes in a textbox?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, xaml, uwp

Is it possible to draw shapes inside of a textbox in XAML? I believe something similar is possible in Windows.Forms, but I'm trying to do this in XAML. This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Example]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you point out why you want to use `RichEditBox` instead of `RichTextBlock` for custom shapes?

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `InlineUIContainer` to insert any XAML control within a `RichTextBlock`.

Here I'm inserting a `TextBlock` within a `Border` but you can also add images, shapes...

```
<RichTextBlock>
  <Paragraph>
    <Run Text="Hello World, this is a text box" />
    <LineBreak/>
    <InlineUIContainer>
      <Border Background="Blue" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Green">
        <TextBlock Text="This is a blue box inside a text box"/>
      </Border>
     </InlineUIContainer>
     <LineBreak/>
     <Run Text="More text" />
   </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

[image: Result of code sample]

Here is the `InlineUIContainer` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer).

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for! I'll test it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Original question uses `TextBox` but you offer `RichTextBlock` which cannot be edited. How to make same thing inside `TextBox`?